# BPSK demodulation

Tags: demodulation, c, bpsk

For experimental reasons i created a function that helps me to modulate a signal using BPSK, the input signal is {1,1,0,1,0} and it works fine

```
void BPSK_mod(unsigned short signal[], float fs, int spb, float output[])
{
   float    ts      =   1.0 / fs;
   float    ti      =   0.0;
   float    two_Pi_f=   2 * M_PI * FREQ;
   int      i,j;
   int      k       =   0;

   for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
       int x = signal[i];
       for( j = 0; j < spb; j++)
       {
          output[k] = sinf(two_Pi_f * ti + (M_PI * x));
          ti += ts;
          k++;
       }
   }
}
```

and this is the plotted signal[image: BPSK modulation]
Now I am confused about how I should do the demodulation ... Can someone give the math and the theory behind it please

Comment: Can I please ask if you have had a look at the [basics of BPSK modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying)? My question is not to put you on the spot. I think that it would be good if you were to clarify exactly what you have had difficulty with because asking generally about PSK demodulation is a bit broad (?)

Comment: I had a look on the link that you have send me earlier bur ... the true question that i dont understand the demodulation process how can I reverse the original signal from this modulated signal